# ¿Porqué no me muestra el resultado del Select?

Tags: php, mysql

cuando quiero obtener el resultado de un `select` de lo que ha seleccionado el usuario, teniendo varios `select` no me realiza en el primer `select` no me da la cantidad seleccionada, pero sin embargo del 2º `option` si.

```
<?php
        // VERIFICAMOS SI HAY SELECCIONADO ALGUN CHECHBOX
        require '../conexion.php';
        $pedido = array();
        $abonos = array();
        if (isset($_POST['btnPedido'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['abonos'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['abonos'] as $selected) {
                    echo "Artículo Seleccionado: ".$selected;
                    //foreach ($_POST['Cantidad'] as $cantidadSeleccionada) {
                        $cantidadSeleccionada = $_POST['Cantidad'];
                        echo "Cantidad antes del if: ".$cantidadSeleccionada;
                        if ($cantidadSeleccionada != 0) {
                            echo " y cantidad seleccionada del producto:".$cantidadSeleccionada." unidades.<br>";
                        }
                    //}
                }
            } else {
                // MOSTRAMOS UNA ALERTA DE QUE NO SE PUEDE CONTINUAR SIN ELEGIR UN ABONO
                $abonos = [];
                echo "<p class='errorAbonosNoSeleccionado'>AVISO IMPORTANTE:</p>";
                echo "<img src='../img/aviso.png' height='50' width='50'>
                No se puede realizar el pedido sin haber seleccionado al menos un abono!.<br>
                Para poder realizar el pedido, hay que tener seleccionado el <b><i><u>checkbox</u></i></b> del Abono/Abonos de los que quieran realizar el pedido, y también seleccionando la cantidad exacta del tipo de abono que necesiten.<br>
                Recuerde que cada abono seleccionando hay que indicar también la cantidad exacta que necesita.";
            }
        }
    ?>

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) >= 1) {
                        // EXISTEN ARTICULOS DEL GRUPO REGISTRADOS
                        echo "<table border='0'>";
                        echo "<tr><th>Nombre del Abono</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Precio/Unidad</th><th>Añadir</th></tr>";
                        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                            $cantidadTotal = $fila['Stock'];
                            echo "<tr><td>".$fila['Nombre']."</td>";
                            echo "<td><select name='Cantidad'>";
                            for ($i=0; $i <= $cantidadTotal; $i++) { 
                                echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select></td>";
                            echo "<td>".$fila['Precio']." €</td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='abonos[]' value='".$fila['Nombre']."'><img src='../img/carro.png' height='50' width='50'></td></tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                        // MOSTRAMOS EL BOTÓN PARA TERMINAR EL PEDIDO.
                        echo "<p class='botonPedido'><button value='terminar' name='btnPedido' type='submit' class='btnPedido'>Tramitar Pedido</button></p>";
                    } else {
                        // NO EXISTEN ARTICULOS DATOS DE ALTA DE DICHO GRUPO
                        echo "<p class='errorAbonosDisponibles'><img src='../img/aviso.png' height='100' width='100'>No existen abonos datos de alta en la plataforma.<br>Comuníqueselo a la Administración para que introduzcan nuevos abonos.</p>";
                    }
```

**Salida seleccionando el primero:**

**Artículo Seleccionado:** Adaptador Bahia 2.5" a 3.5" Coolbox.

**Cantidad antes del if:** 0

**Salida seleccionado el segundo:**

**Artículo Seleccionado:** Disco Duro SSD Kingston 240GB UV500.

**Cantidad antes del if:** 4 y

**Cantidad seleccionada del producto:** 4 unidades.

¿Porqué cuando selecciono el primero no me muestra la cantidad? si cuando selecciono el segundo me lo muestra perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado, despues de estar tanto tiempo dando vueltas. El problema es porque indico el mismo nombre al select.